# How can I extract the Short Operating System name using regex in Groovy?

Tags: regex, groovy

I am trying to obtain the output "Windows Server 2008"  from the following input string:"The operating system in the remote workstation is Microsoft Windows Server 2008 R2 Enterprise"

But I only get:  "Windows Server"  not the "2008"

I tried in www.regex101.com and I believe I have the right regex

```
def sentence = "The operating system in the remote workstation is Microsoft Windows Server 2008 R2 Enterprise"

def regexWinWorkstation = "Microsoft (Windows [a-zA-Z0-9]+)"
def regexWinServer = "Microsoft (Windows Server [a-zA-Z0-9]+)"

def result = sentence.find(regexWinWorkstation) {
    println it[1]
}

if (!result) {
    result = sentence.find(regexWinServer){
    println it[1]}
}
```

Expected output: "Windows Server 2008"
Actual output:"Windows Server"

Comment: The regex matching operator is `=~`. See https://ideone.com/N7gYbz. I am not quite sure what logic you are trying to implement here as both regexps find a match here.

Comment: Thank you Wiktor, the output I am looking for is "Windows Server 2008" . I ran the code you provided and the output is "Windows Server".
I replace the regex matching operator  `=~` in my code and again I get the same output "Windows Server" . `result = sentence.find(regexWinServer)` does the same as the regex operator in Groovy.

Comment: My logic is: I have thousands of entries that give the long name for an operating system " Microsoft Windows Server 2008 R2 Standard", "Microsoft Windows Server 2008 R2 Enterprise", "Microsoft Windows 2016 Enterprise", "Microsoft Windows 10 Professional", etc etc .  so what I need is to have a simplified version of them like : Windows Server 2008, Windows Server 2016, Windows 7, Windows 10, etc etc . be This simplified Operating System name will be used in other code (separate from the one shown in this question).

Comment: Please edit the question with more details. I am not sure, if https://ideone.com/L5u9sd will help you.

Comment: The first regular expression `regexWinWorkstation` matches _"Windows Server"_ then hits a space, so stops.  The second regular expression in this example is not used

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def sentences = [
  "The operating system in the remote workstation is Microsoft Windows Server 2008 R2 Enterprise",
  "The operating system is Microsoft Windows 10 Professional",
  "The operating system is Windows XP"
]
def regexWinOptionalServer = /(?<=Microsoft )?Windows (Server )?[a-zA-Z0-9]+/

sentences.each{
  println it.find(regexWinOptionalServer)
}
```

prints

```
Windows Server 2008
Windows 10
Windows XP
```

Comment: Nice...  I think they want to drop the `Microsoft` though, so maybe the regex should be `/Microsoft (Windows (Server )?[a-zA-Z0-9]+)/", and then the find: `sentence.find(regexWinOptionalServer) { it[1] }`

Comment: thanks @tim_yates - i hadn't noticed they wanted to drop `Microsoft` - added a lookbehind to the regex to catch it

Comment: Thank you very much @thehole. This regex and code got returns the right output.

Comment: Thank you @tim_yates  for your comments, if you have a moment: any resource you recommend to learn better regex specifically for Groovy?